# javascript forEach - add addEventListener on all buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not so skilled with javascript so I'm looking for a little help.
I'm using a script found on Codrops (3D Grid Effect - http://tympanus.net/Development/3DGridEffect/).

All is working fine as expected but I'm trying to "modify" it for my needs.

Basically, I want to trigger the "effect" NOT clicking on the whole container but on a button placed inside it.

The structure I'm using is:

```
    <section class="grid3d vertical" id="grid3d">
        <div class="grid-wrap">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="box"><div class="btn-click-me">Click to Show</div></div>
                <div class="box"><div class="btn-click-me">Click to Show</div></div>
                <div class="box"><div class="btn-click-me">Click to Show</div></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <div class="dummy-img"></div>
                <p class="dummy-text">Some text</p>
                <p class="dummy-text">Some more text</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>
            <!-- ... -->
            <span class="loading"></span>
            <span class="icon close-content"></span>
        </div>
    </section>

<script>
            new grid3D( document.getElementById( 'grid3d' ) );
        </script>
```

And the script (js) is

```
/**
 * grid3d.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2014, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    function grid3D( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    // any options you might want to configure
    grid3D.prototype.options = {};

    grid3D.prototype._init = function() {
        // grid wrapper
        this.gridWrap = this.el.querySelector( 'div.grid-wrap' );
        // grid element
        this.grid = this.gridWrap.querySelector( 'div.grid' );
        // main grid items
        this.gridItems = [].slice.call( this.grid.children );
        // default sizes for grid items
        this.itemSize = { width : this.gridItems[0].offsetWidth, height : this.gridItems[0].offsetHeight };
        // content
        this.contentEl = this.el.querySelector( 'div.content' );
        // content items
        this.contentItems = [].slice.call( this.contentEl.children );
        // close content cross
        this.close = this.contentEl.querySelector( 'span.close-content' );
        // loading indicator
        this.loader = this.contentEl.querySelector( 'span.loading' );
        // support: support for pointer events, transitions and 3d transforms
        this.support = support.pointerevents && support.csstransitions && support.csstransforms3d;
        // init events
        this._initEvents();
    };

    grid3D.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        // open the content element when clicking on the main grid items
        this.gridItems.forEach( function( item, idx ) {
            item.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                self._showContent( idx );
            } );
        } );

        // close the content element
        this.close.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            self._hideContent();
        } );

        if( this.support ) {
            // window resize
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() { self._resizeHandler(); } );

            // trick to prevent scrolling when animation is running (opening only)
            // this prevents that the back of the placeholder does not stay positioned in a wrong way
            window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
                if ( self.isAnimating ) {
                    window.scrollTo( self.scrollPosition ? self.scrollPosition.x : 0, self.scrollPosition ? self.scrollPosition.y : 0 );
                }
                else {
                    self.scrollPosition = { x : window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft, y : window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop };
                    // change the grid perspective origin as we scroll the page
                    self._scrollHandler();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // creates placeholder and animates it to fullscreen
    // in the end of the animation the content is shown
    // a loading indicator will appear for 1 second to simulate a loading period
    grid3D.prototype._showContent = function( pos ) {
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;

        var self = this,
            loadContent = function() {
                // simulating loading...
                setTimeout( function() {
                    // hide loader
                    classie.removeClass( self.loader, 'show' );
                    // in the end of the transition set class "show" to respective content item
                    classie.addClass( self.contentItems[ pos ], 'show' );
                }, 1000 );
                // show content area
                classie.addClass( self.contentEl, 'show' );
                // show loader
                classie.addClass( self.loader, 'show' );
                classie.addClass( document.body, 'noscroll' );
                self.isAnimating = false;
            };

        // if no support just load the content (simple fallback - no animation at all)
        if( !this.support ) {
            loadContent();
            return false;
        }

        var currentItem = this.gridItems[ pos ],
            itemContent = currentItem.innerHTML;

        // create the placeholder
        this.placeholder = this._createPlaceholder(itemContent );

        // set the top and left of the placeholder to the top and left of the clicked grid item (relative to the grid)
        this.placeholder.style.left = currentItem.offsetLeft + 'px';
        this.placeholder.style.top = currentItem.offsetTop + 'px';

        // append placeholder to the grid
        this.grid.appendChild( this.placeholder );

        // and animate it
        var animFn = function() {
            // give class "active" to current grid item (hides it)
            classie.addClass( currentItem, 'active' );
            // add class "view-full" to the grid-wrap
            classie.addClass( self.gridWrap, 'view-full' );
            // set width/height/left/top of placeholder
            self._resizePlaceholder();
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) === -1 ) return false;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                loadContent();
            };
            self.placeholder.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        };

        setTimeout( animFn, 25 );
    };

    grid3D.prototype._hideContent = function() {
        var self = this,
            contentItem = this.el.querySelector( 'div.content > .show' ),
            currentItem = this.gridItems[ this.contentItems.indexOf( contentItem ) ];

        classie.removeClass( contentItem, 'show' );
        classie.removeClass( this.contentEl, 'show' );
        // without the timeout there seems to be some problem in firefox
        setTimeout( function() { classie.removeClass( document.body, 'noscroll' ); }, 25 );
        // that's it for no support..
        if( !this.support ) return false;

        classie.removeClass( this.gridWrap, 'view-full' );

        // reset placeholder style values
        this.placeholder.style.left = currentItem.offsetLeft + 'px';
        this.placeholder.style.top = currentItem.offsetTop + 'px';
        this.placeholder.style.width = this.itemSize.width + 'px';
        this.placeholder.style.height = this.itemSize.height + 'px';

        var onEndPlaceholderTransFn = function( ev ) {
            this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndPlaceholderTransFn );
            // remove placeholder from grid
            self.placeholder.parentNode.removeChild( self.placeholder );
            // show grid item again
            classie.removeClass( currentItem, 'active' );
        };
        this.placeholder.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndPlaceholderTransFn );
    }

    // function to create the placeholder
    /*
    <div class="placeholder">
        <div class="front">[content]</div>
        <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
    */
    grid3D.prototype._createPlaceholder = function( content ) {
        var front = document.createElement( 'div' );
        front.className = 'front';
        front.innerHTML = content;
        var back = document.createElement( 'div' );
        back.className = 'back';
        back.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        var placeholder = document.createElement( 'div' );
        placeholder.className = 'placeholder';
        placeholder.appendChild( front );
        placeholder.appendChild( back );
        return placeholder;
    };

    grid3D.prototype._scrollHandler = function() {
        var self = this;
        if( !this.didScroll ) {
            this.didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( function() { self._scrollPage(); }, 60 );
        }
    };

    // changes the grid perspective origin as we scroll the page
    grid3D.prototype._scrollPage = function() {
        var perspY = scrollY() + getViewportH() / 2;
        this.gridWrap.style.WebkitPerspectiveOrigin = '50% ' + perspY + 'px';
        this.gridWrap.style.MozPerspectiveOrigin = '50% ' + perspY + 'px';
        this.gridWrap.style.perspectiveOrigin = '50% ' + perspY + 'px';
        this.didScroll = false;
    };

    grid3D.prototype._resizeHandler = function() {
        var self = this;
        function delayed() {
            self._resizePlaceholder();
            self._scrollPage();
            self._resizeTimeout = null;
        }
        if ( this._resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( this._resizeTimeout );
        }
        this._resizeTimeout = setTimeout( delayed, 50 );
    }

    grid3D.prototype._resizePlaceholder = function() {
        // need to recalculate all these values as the size of the window changes
        this.itemSize = { width : this.gridItems[0].offsetWidth, height : this.gridItems[0].offsetHeight };
        if( this.placeholder ) {
            // set the placeholders top to "0 - grid offsetTop" and left to "0 - grid offsetLeft"
            this.placeholder.style.left = Number( -1 * ( this.grid.offsetLeft - scrollX() ) ) + 'px';
            this.placeholder.style.top = Number( -1 * ( this.grid.offsetTop - scrollY() ) ) + 'px';
            // set the placeholders width to windows width and height to windows height
            this.placeholder.style.width = getViewportW() + 'px';
            this.placeholder.style.height = getViewportH() + 'px';
        }
    }

    // add to global namespace
    window.grid3D = grid3D;

})( window );
```

Now, I'm aware that the "crucial" portion of the code where I have to look is:

> // open the content element when clicking on the main grid items
>         this.gridItems.forEach( function(item, idx ) {
>             item.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
>                 item._showContent( idx );           } );        } );

So, my question again: how to trigger the event when the div (button) class "click-me" is clicked on every "boxes"?

Thanks to all in advance (i'm struggling with it for hours...)

Comment: java? jQuery? What about 'heal the world' tag?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Typed with phone, autocompletion!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at the example here,

http://jsfiddle.net/y0mbn94n/

I have added some intialisation to get your particular classes

```
    // get grid buttons and then make an iterable array out of them        
    this.gridButtons = this.el.querySelectorAll('button.btn-click-me');
    this.gridButtonItems = [].slice.call(this.gridButtons);
```

and changed the function which iterates and adds a listener.

```
    // open the content element when clicking on the buttonsItems
    this.gridButtonItems.forEach(function (item, idx) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function () {
            self._showContent(idx);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to call a callback function when the user clicks on a button:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-click-me');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var self = buttons[i];

    self.addEventListener('click', function (event) {  
        // prevent browser's default action
        event.preventDefault();

        // call your awesome function here
        MyAwesomeFunction(this); // 'this' refers to the current button on for loop
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

with the structure  given

```
    <div class="grid-wrap">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="box"><div class="btn-click-me">Click to Show</div></div>
            <div class="box"><div class="btn-click-me">Click to Show</div></div>
            <div class="box"><div class="btn-click-me">Click to Show</div></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

you just have to change the line you've said to:

```
item.children[0].addEventListener( 'click', function() {
```

as the btn-click-me would be the first child of each item.

If you would like a more generic solution you could use:

```
item.getElementsByClassName('btn-click-me')[0].addEventListener( 'click', function() {
```

where **bnt-click-me** would be the class of the button that you would want to bind the click event. Notice that `[0]` so you can select the very first item of the array, as `getElementsByClassName` will return one, even if there's only one element.

But if you say you're just starting with javascript y really recommend you using *jQuery*, it's selectors are much easier than *vanilla javascript*.

Comment: Hello Alvaro, thank you! And if I want the click to trigger NOT on the first child but on a child with a specific class? Thanks again!

Comment: I've didn't saw your comment, but I've improved the answer so it could work for any selector :)